# serialize form while input fields name are in array jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a form in which input are like

```
<input type="text" value="" name="fieldval[3][4][]" >
```

now when i serialize this form using jquery i am getting result like this

```
app_id=1&app_id=2&app_id=3&fieldval%5B2%5D%5B2%5D%5B%5D=1&fieldval%5B2%5D%5B2%5D%5B%5D=day&fieldval%5B3%5D%5B4%5D%5B%5D=23&fieldval%5B1%5D%5B1%5D%5B%5D=1&fieldval%5B1%5D%5B1%5D%5B%5D=mb&fieldval%5B1%5D%5B3%5D%5B%5D=200&fieldval%5B1%5D%5B3%5D%5B%5D=mb
```

please tell me the right way how to get values in proper way from this type input field.

now when I use serializeArray i get array like

```
 Array
(
    [step_number] => 4
    [app_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

    [formdata] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => app_id[]
                    [value] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => app_id[]
                    [value] => 2
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => app_id[]
                    [value] => 3
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [name] => fieldval[2][2][]
                    [value] => 1
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [name] => fieldval[2][2][]
                    [value] => day
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [name] => fieldval[3][4][]
                    [value] => 23
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [name] => fieldval[1][1][]
                    [value] => 1
                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [name] => fieldval[1][1][]
                    [value] => mb
                )

            [8] => Array
                (
                    [name] => fieldval[1][3][]
                    [value] => 200
                )

            [9] => Array
                (
                    [name] => fieldval[1][3][]
                    [value] => mb
                )

            [10] => Array
                (
                    [name] => plan_type
                    [value] => free
                )

            [11] => Array
                (
                    [name] => price
                    [value] => 
                )

            [12] => Array
                (
                    [name] => sell_type
                    [value] => up
                )

        )

)
```

Now i want to change this array format to like this

```
Array
```

(
    [app_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

```
[fieldval] => Array
    (
        [2] => Array
            (
                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 1
                        [1] => day
                    )

            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 23
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 1
                        [1] => mb
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 200
                        [1] => mb
                    )

            )

    )

[plan_type] => free
[price] => 
[sell_type] => up
```

)

how can i do this

Comment: if you want to retrieve values in php then try: `print_r($_GET);`

Comment: I am using post method in my ajax code. when i print through get methods it returns blank and when i print using post it returns values in same format i mentioned in question

Comment: fiddle it, someone

Comment: what you meaning @Chay22

Answer (score 0):

Use a form tag with id like this.

```
<form id="my-form-name" method="POST" action="http://something.com/">
   <!-- Your fields here-->
   <input type="text" value="" name="fieldval[]" />
   <input type="text" value="" name="fieldval[]" />
</form>
```

In your JS

```
var data =$("#my-form-name").serializeArray();
console.log(data);
```

Now you have an array with your inputs data.

Comment: it gives me array like this
`Array
(
    [formdata] => Array
        (
               [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => fieldval[2][2][]
                    [value] => 1
                )
        )
)`



I want this like 
`[fieldval] => Array
        (
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1
                            [1] => day
                        )

                )
        )`

Comment: You can use a foreach to get data in your backend.

Answer (score 0):

Here is full example

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="frm">
<input type="text" value="3" name="fieldval[1][4][]" >
    <input type="text" value="43" name="fieldval[2][4][]" >
    <input type="text" value="22" name="fieldval[3][4][]" >
    <input type="text" value="65" name="fieldval[4][4][]" >
<input type="button" value="click" id="click">
</form>
<div id="results"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#click").click(function(){

        var data =$("#frm").serializeArray();
        var fields = $( ":input" ).serializeArray();
            jQuery.each( fields, function( i, field ) {
                $( "#results" ).append( field.value + " " );
    });


    });
});
</script>
```

I hope this will help

Comment: it gives me array like this
`Array
(
    [formdata] => Array
        (
               [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => fieldval[2][2][]
                    [value] => 1
                )
        )
)`



I want this like 
`[fieldval] => Array
        (
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1
                            [1] => day
                        )

                )
        )`